# Custom error pages for the new blog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, 404-not-found

Currently going to a page that doesn't exist on the blog, like http://blog.stackexchange.com/secretunicornpage gives the standard IIS error page.

On other (all?) network sites you get a custom page, such as https://stackexchange.com/secretunicornpage

Could a custom error page be added?

Comment: Also, could a secret unicorn page be added (if it doesn't already exist)?

Comment: and same for [generic error page](http://blog.stackexchange.com/error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The new 404 page is live.](http://blog.stackexchange.com/haha-i-dunt-exist)

<sup>just this time, please don't follow the advice in the last sentence.</sup>

<sup><sup>credits go to me and [Jon Chan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/242868/jon-chan)</sup></sup>

Comment: +1 for sharing the screenshot? Looks very clean and professional.

Comment: I deleted my answer which apparently it looked as a comment. Anyway, I am glad to see there is NO PANDA HERE image on this upcoming 404 error page. Save bandwidth!!